# Copying build.gradle code from react native docs cause build error

Tags: react-native, gradle

I'm preparing app for publishing, but I don't know gradle anyhow. On this page: https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android they say to copy code to build.gradle file, but after I did it and run

```
cd android
./gradlew bundleRelease
```

command I get error: `build file 'C:\pathToMyApp\android\build.gradle': 41: unexpected token: ... @ line 41, column 5.`

My whole build.gradle file looks like this:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2")

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}

android {
    ...
    defaultConfig { ... }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            ...
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}
```

It's probably because of those 3 dots, but after removing them I get another error:

`Could not find method android() for arguments [build_somelongstring_run_closure2@otherstring] on root project 'MyApp' of type org.gradle.api.Project.`

Answer (score 0):

I was editing wrong build.gradle file - the one from android catalog.

Correct one is in android/app catalog.